# Regular expression incorporating an exclusion (ie "does not contain") for grep

Tags: regex, grep, filtering

I'm trying to filter webserver log files using grep. I need to output all lines containing **65.55.**  but exclude those matching lines which contain **msnbot**.

My starting point is this - but it doesn't work:

```
grep "^.*65\.55\..*(!msnbot).*$" ex100101.log > results.txt
```

I'm using grep for Windows (hence double quotes) but I doubt this matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd just do it with two greps:

```
grep "65.55" ex100101.log | grep -v msnbot > results.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

normally, you use 2 greps. one to grep the pattern you want, the other with `-v` option to exclude the pattern. however you can use awk, which does it all in one process.

```
awk '/.*65\.55.*/ && !/msnbot/' ext100101.log >results.txt
```

you can download awk for windows [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm).

Answer (score 1):

If grep supports lookaheads, you could use

```
grep "^.*65\.55\.(?:.(?!msnbot))*$" ex100101.log > results.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to produce any results in my setup

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to pipe the output of the first command and exclude lines using grep -v

```
grep FINDPATTERN | grep -v EXCLUDEPATTERN LOGFILE > results.txt
```

Comment: The LOGFILE needs to be passed to the first grep, not the second.